# Objective-C Memory Management: When do I [release]?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am still new to this Memory Management stuff *(Garbage Collector took care of everything in Java)*, but as far as I understand *if you allocate memory* for an object then *you have to release that memory back* to the computer as soon as you are finished with your object.

```
myObject = [Object alloc];
```

and

```
[myObject release];
```

Right now I just have 3 parts in my *Objective-C .m file*: **@Interface**, **@Implementation** and **main**. I released my object at the end of the program next to these guys:

```
[pool drain];
return 0;
```

But what if this program were to be a lot more complicated, would it be okay to release **myObject** at the end of the program?

I guess a better question would be when do I release an object's allocated memory? How do I know where to place `[myObject release];`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a little over-simplified, but in general, you are going to want to release it where you declared it.

If you declare an object INSIDE a particular method call, then by definition, you will be done with that object (or at least that handle to that object) at the end of that method call... release it then.

If you declare an object as an instance variable, then by definition you will be done with it when that instance is destroyed... release it in the dealloc method of that class.

Keep in mind that "release" does not equal "destroy." When passing objects around in your application, it may make sense to have more than one handle to that object stored in different places... in that case "release" means "I'm done with this object, but someone else may still be using it." Deallocation only occurs when the number of "handles" (retain count) reaches zero.

Apple has some fantastic documentation on memory management, I would check it out at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have three kinds of objects, each with a different pattern.

**Transients Objects**

In general, you should `autorelease` transient objects. These are objects that are allocated locally and do not need to exist beyond the method in which they are called. Or they are passed around from method to method.

**Chain of Ownership**

When one object exists as an instance field inside another, you should `release` the "owned" (or "child") object when the "owner" (or "parent") object goes out of existence. This is done in the `dealloc` method of the parent object:

```
- (void) dealloc {
    [child release]; // child was declared as an instance variable
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**Lifetime of the Program**

When an object is intended to exist for the lifetime of the program, it usually isn't necessary to call `release` at all, unless some kind of resource cleanup needs to occur. You can put this in `applicationWillTerminate:`, which you can look up in Apple's documentation.

(You should probably avoid having such objects, but that is a discussion for another question.)

Comment: Please be noted that `applicationWillTerminate:` is not called in iOS 4 most of the time.

Comment: Good call. It's not a method I typically need anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think in terms of ownership. When you take ownership of an object by calling **alloc**, **new** or **retain**, you're also responsible for releasing it, either by calling **autorelease** when you return an owned object to the caller, or by calling **release**.

**A general rule is:**

*Local variable*: release it within the same method. When you want to return it to the caller, use **autorelease**

*Class member*: release it in the **dealloc** method